# Let $|z|<1$ be given. Show that $|z|^n$ converges to $0$ by definition.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Let $z$ be a complex number with $|z|<1$. Show that $|z|^n$ converges to $0$ by definition.

**Attempt:**
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary given. Choose a positive integer $N$ with $N>\log_{|z|} \epsilon$ such that for any $n>N$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
n>N &\implies n> \log_{|z|} \epsilon \\
&\implies \log_{|z|} |z|^n > \log_{|z|} \epsilon \\
&\implies |z|^n < \epsilon \\
&\implies |z|^n-0<\epsilon \\
&\implies ||z|^n-0| < \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, $|z|^n$ converges to $0$.

Am I true?

Comment: By definition of what?

Comment: Yeah, looks good

Comment: Aesthetically and technically, the use of $\log$ is (massive) overkill. If it matters, there is an elementary bound: If $z \neq 0$ and $u$ is defined by $1 + u = 1/|z|$, then $1 + nu \leq (1 + u)^{n}$ for every positive integer $n$, so $|z|^{n} \leq 1/(1+nu)$. Now use the Archimedean property of the reals. (The case $z = 0$ needs to be handled separately, but there's nothing to prove.)

Comment: It looks basically correct. However, there are two points that I want to make: $(1)$ If $z=0$, then your proof doesn't work, because $\log_0\epsilon$ is not well-defined. Although the case $z=0$ is trivial, I suggest that you start your proof with "If $z=0$, then the result clearly holds. If $z\neq0$, then for any $\epsilon>0\cdots$". $(2)$ In your last $\Rightarrow$, I won't say "$A<\epsilon\Rightarrow |A|<\epsilon$". You should be careful in every "$\Rightarrow$". $(3)$ I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang that the use of $\log$ is overkill.

Comment: @Feng What if: $|z|^n<\epsilon$ then since $||z|^n|=|z|^n$, we have $||z|^n-0|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @PitikKepit Now, this is irrefutable.

Comment: @Feng OK got it now. Thanks sir.